# How to calculate the density function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $(X, Y, Z)$ be a randomly absolutely continuous vector, whose density function is
given by:

$$f_{(X,Y,Z)}(x,y,z)=\frac{6}{(1+x+y+z)^4}$$

For $x,y,z>0$. Calculate the density function of $W=X+Y+Z$.

My idea was to calculate $\mathbb{P}(W\leq t)$ given $t>0$ and define the region $A=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R_{+}^3}: x+y+z\leq t\}$ and fix $z$, using the fact:

$$\mathbb{P}(W\leq t)=\mathbb{P}((x,y,z)\in A)$$

My question is to know if this idea is ok, or if there is another way to do it.

Comment: A change of variables is useful here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2579769/321264.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you wish to calculate:

$\qquad\begin{align}\Bbb P(W\leq t) &=\Bbb P(X+Y+Z\leq t)\\&=\int_0^t\int_0^{t-x}\int_0^{t-x-y} f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)~\mathrm d z~\mathrm d y~\mathrm d x\end{align}$

Also, since you actually want to find the density of $W$, you can go straight to

$\qquad\begin{align} f_W(t) &=\mathbf 1_{0\lt t} \int_0^{t}\int_0^{t-x} f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,t-x-y)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x\end{align}$